# Mount NFS from PowerShell on Windows 2012 and be visible elsewhere

Tags: powershell, nfs, windows-server-2012

I'd like to mount an NFS share from Windows 2012 using PowerShell and have this mount be visible in contexts other than the PowerShell session that invoked it. If I use the New-PSDrive command (cmdlet?), e.g.:

```
New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\10.40.1.1\export\isos
```

Then it will mount the NFS server to the Z drive, but I can't access this drive in, say, File Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kernel Panic](https://serverfault.com/users/47971/kernel-panic) is correct about the PSDrive cmdlet being usable only within the PowerShell environment. The TechNet article ‘[Using the New –PSDrive Cmdlet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176915.aspx)’ states ‘Mapped drives last only as long as your current Windows PowerShell session.’ However, you can create a configuration file that will re-map the drives every time you start PowerShell.

Further, the TechNet Article ‘[Converting the Windows Script Host MapNetworkDrive Method](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730992.aspx)’ also states that any drive created with the –PSDrive cmdlet ‘can be used exactly like any other mapped network drive as long as you are working in Windows PowerShell.’ This is a PowerShell Drive and not a true mapped drive. This article goes on to show that you can map drives in PowerShell using the Net Use command:

```
net use z: \\server\folder
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: "‘Mapped drives last only as long as your current Windows PowerShell session." No, with the Persist flag it isn't bound to the session.

Answer (score 6):

You need to use the **Persist** flag.

```
New-PSDrive Z -PsProvider FileSystem -Root \\10.40.1.1\export\isos -Persist
```

> -Persist
>
> Creates a Windows mapped network drive. Mapped network drives are saved in Windows on the local computer. They are **persistent**, not
>   session-specific, and can be viewed and managed in File Explorer and
>   other tools. **The name of the drive must be a letter**, such as D or E.
>   The value of the Root parameter must be a UNC path to a different
>   computer. The value of the PSProvider parameter must be FileSystem. To
>   disconnect a Windows mapped network drive, use the Remove-PSDrive
>   cmdlet. When you disconnect a Windows mapped network drive, the
>   mapping is permanently deleted from the computer, not just deleted
>   from the current session. NOTE: Mapped network drives are specific to
>   a user account. Mapped network drives that you create in sessions that
>   are started with the "Run as administrator" option or with the
>   credential of another user are not visible in session that started
>   without explicit credentials or with the credentials of the current
>   user.

See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849829.aspx

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the PSDrive cmdlet, prior to Powershell 3, is a mapping between the shell and some data store. This will not carry outside of the 'shell'. Powershell 3.0 has the Persistent parameter which can do what you want.

Comment: I'm running PowerShell Version 3.0 on the server. If I add the '-persist' flag, I don't see a change in behavior.

Comment: Are you running it with elevated credentials? Are they different creds than the user for whom you are mapping the share?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, the CMD `mount` command used to work for me until I realized that, contrary to its' documented options, it only maps credentials (be it domain, LDS or system) of the **logged in user**, i.e., the user that started the command.

Given the UAC control is in place, this effectively means the command only works for one's user session, in other words, if you want to use alternate credentials, you need to use `runas`, which itself only lasts for the CMD session.

This is *despite the fact it itself supports these options:* `-u:username -p:*`.

There was a hotfix KB2684578, but it is *"no longer available"*.

(According to the same KB article, the `net` command suffers from the same fallacy.)

Answer (score -1):

The `mount` command from the command line.

```
mount <NFS_Server_IP>:<Share_Path> <Mount_Point>
```

Comment: I believe New-NfsShare is for exporting an NFS drive, not mounting one. And, according to PowerShell, "mount" is an alias for "New-PSDrive", so I suspect the behavior is similar.

Comment: @LorinHochstein have you checked the NFS permissions on the server?

Comment: The permissions seem to be OK, as far as I can tell. The mount does work, it just only works within the PowerShell session that it was invoked in.